# Can not set the content of button as it doesn't have a contentpropertyattribute on xamarin page

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, layout

I'm trying to add three button images on the same row inside a StackLayout.

The first button image doesn't show any error, but the problem is with two other buttons.

Here is the code:

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height ="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="loginlogo.png"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="5"  Spacing="5" Grid.Row="1">

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text ="editor is used for collecting text that is expected to take more than one line." 
                            TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="100" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="facebook"  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Image="Fb.png">
                    <Button.Image Aspect="AspectFit" />
                </Button>

            <Button  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Image="LINKEDIN.png">
                <Button.Image Aspect="AspectFit" />
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="YB"  WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Image="YOUTUBE.png">
                <Button.Image Aspect="AspectFit" />
            </Button>

        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1" >
        <Label Text="sample text" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

This is  the exact error I receive:

> Position 35:18. Can not set the content of Button as it doesn't have a
>   ContentPropertyAttribute

Position 35 is the third button named *YB*

I don't understand where the problem is. 
Any advice will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Forms.Button.Image` is an `FileImageSource` and thus there is no `Aspect` property to it. This abstract control is converted to a platform native one and full image control of how it appears within that button on each platform is not exposed.

But on `Xamarin.Forms.Image` there is an `Aspect` property.

If you need to control the aspect ratio, you could created a custom button renderer and handle it at the platform level, or just use a `Xamarin.Forms.Image` and set a tab gesture on them.